# Ensure mime-type is set correctly in Subversion when missing as a property?

Tags: apache, svn, mime-types

We have currently the problem that a lot of files stored in Subversion are missing the mime-type. Depending on the browser you are using, when surfing a Subversion directory and clicking on a link, you see the text e.g. of a PDF and not the PDF rendered in Acrobat Reader.

The obvious solution to this is to set the property in Subversion, in this example to set `svn:mime-type` to `application/pdf` and to set the relevant section in auto-props in the Subversion client configuration file. But a lot of our users don't understand that, and we don't control all their settings, so there will be added over and over again files to the repositories where the correct mime-type will be missing.

What are the options to correct this, and what are the drawbacks in using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but the recipe that worked for us I found under https://serverfault.com/questions/451500/is-it-possible-for-the-subversion-apache-module-to-serve-html-files-with-an-html

So in case you want to reach something similar, try that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache HTTP Server to serve your Subversion repositories then you should configure default media types with help of mod_mime module. See docs at [Apache Module mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html).

Generally speaking you need to add the following strings to Apache config and point `TypesConfig` to your `mime.types` file.

```
LoadModule mime_module bin/mod_mime.so
TypesConfig <path-to-mime.types-file>
```

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. I will get in touch with our operating team, and they have to modify the configuration of our Apache server. This will need some time, so I will come back in ~ a week.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to install a pre-commit hook script which checks for the appropriate mime-type on all files in an incoming commit, and reject the commit if it doesn't meet your requirements (providing an informative message to the user telling them why they can't commit).

Eventually, users (the ones who care about working efficiently, anyway) should get the hint and take care of adding the property themselves, or ask you how to set up their system so they don't have to.

You might see suggestions that amount to modifying the commit while in transit. Ignore them. They are dangerous and will lead to confusion for users. You might also see recommendations to have a post-commit hook script to immediately make a second commit using a server-side working copy. This is less dangerous, but could lead to a race condition. It will also slow everyone down, and make the committing user's working copy immediately out of date which will be incredibly annoying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have hoped that there is some Apache magic we could use ... I know the Subversion options, and I don't like them. It is nice to train all persons, but sometimes, you have to find a workaround that works equally well ...